# Custom statusText not sent to client after enabling SSL

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl, https

I observed a weird behaviour after enabling SSL in my ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application. First off, here a little explanation of what I’m trying to do: Send a request to the server and display an error message if the model validation fails. Here is the Action-filter I use for this purpose:

```
 public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext pFilterContext)
    {
      if (!pFilterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        var msg = «Custom errormessage»
        pFilterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, msg);
      }
    }
  }
```

On the clientside ($.ajax()) I do nothing more than this:

```
alert(jqXhr.statusText);
```

This all worked perfectly fine until I set up the application in order to  support SSL-Encryption. This is where the strange part comes up. On my local working-machine instead of the custom errormessage I get an alert containing the string («error»), which I assume is the default text set by the jQuery library. If a publish the app to the remote webserver, however (Windows Azure in my case), I get the custom text.
According to Chrome's console I get nothing back from the server, when I run the app on my local host

```
jquery.js:8706 POST https://localhost:44300/my/url  400 ()
```

This is what it looks like on the remote server

```
jquery.js:8706 POST https://myurl.azurewebsites.net/my/url  400 (Custom errormessage)
```

Here some Configuration code I used to set up HTTPS.

In the web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Account/Login" timeout="1440" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="true"></forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration pConfig)
    {
      pConfig.MessageHandlers.Add(new RequireHttpsHandler());
      //...
    }
```

RequireHttpsHandler.cs:

```
  public class RequireHttpsHandler : DelegatingHandler
  {
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage pRequest, CancellationToken pCancellationToken)
    {
      if (pRequest.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
      {
        return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
          {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
              Content = new StringContent("HTTPS required!")
            };
            return response;
          }, pCancellationToken);
      }
      return base.SendAsync(pRequest, pCancellationToken);
    }
  }
}
```

FilterConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection pFilters)
{
  pFilters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
}
```

Does anyone know what could be the source of my issue and how to fix it? Google could not help me this time.

Comment: If you add an error handler to that ajax request, it would probably give you a more specific error. Did you check the console for errors as well, especially CORS errors.

Comment: The alert gets called within the error handler and I'm 100% sure the data must be there as i saw it within responseText's <title>-property. Cors errors? What do you mean by that? I couldn't find anything like this in Chromes console

Comment: Something like `$.ajax(...).fail(function() { console.log(arguments) })`

Comment: This is exactly the problem I have. arguments[0].statusText comes up with "error" here instead of "custom message". No ideas?